# How to prevent InvalidOperationException caused by List in a multithreaded application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 2 `Threads`. One of them **repeatedly modifies** a `List`. The other **tries to access** the `List` but it usually throws a `System.InvalidOperationException`.

I've tried `lock`ing the `List` object but it did not help.

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    // A thread that repeatedly modifies the list
    Thread listAddThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while(true)
        {
            list.Add(0);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    });

    listAddThread.Start();

    // Wait to fill up the list
    Thread.Sleep(50);

    // Lock the list from other threads till the operation completes
    lock(list)
    {
        foreach(var entry in list)
        {
            DoSomeStuffThatTakesALotOfTime(entry);
        }
    }
}

public static void DoSomeStuffThatTakesALotOfTime(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I expect the `lock(list)` will prevent other threads from accessing the `list`.

Comment: Take a look at `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

Comment: First, you do not use `lock` to synchronize all accesses to the list done by your code. Why would you expect that `lock` magically takes care of those list accesses that you don't have synchronized with `lock`?  Second, there are collections that are by nature thread-safe, allowing concurrent accesses. Look at the collections in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent) namespace...

Comment: You're locking the list at the producer and consumer side? i.e. if you're going to add stuff then you lock and unlock when complete. When you read/count stuff then you lock, get the value(s) and unlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two different blocks of code use `lock(list)` then each must acquire the lock. One won't acquire the lock and execute until the other has completed and released the lock. (That, of course, is why we use it - so that the two blocks of code won't execute simultaneously.)

But in this case you're only using the `lock` once, in the second part of the method. Since there is no other "competing" code that might ever attempt to acquire that lock, it doesn't do anything at all.

There's also no guarantee that `listAddThread` will complete before the second part of the method starts to iterate the list. That means you might start trying to iterate the list while that other thread you started is adding to it. Based on the exception, that's not a maybe - that's what *is* happening.

The `while(true)` loop will never stop executing (true is always true), so regardless of whether the wait is 50ms or 5000ms you'll never stop adding to the list. But even if that loop did terminate, there's no guarantee that the 50ms wait will either be enough time or will be too much time. It's better to just write our code so that everything that needs to execute in sequence *always* executes in sequence, not by trying to guess how long something will take.